# date time format null values return default time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

i am currently working on codeigniter project.i have a database name is `"student_detail"` the table value have like this

```
  payment_date
1 NULL
2 NULL
3 2017-12-06 08:47:40

payment_date column is a DATETIME format
```

. when i print this column it returns like this

```
payment_date
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00
3 2017-12-06 08:47:40
```

but i need to return as NULL not default time format.

Comment: where is your php  code?

Comment: i was just printing this table using print_r() method

Comment: Show your `php` code

Answer (score 1):

Update your payment date field in database. Setit default to null.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `payment_date` `payment_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is just to give you an idea. I can help you precisely if you post your PHP code in question.

Before you get the date variable and print it with `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($payment_date))` function, you must check if it is having `NULL` value or not.

```
if($payment_date != NULL)
{
    date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($payment_date));
}
```

Comment: why all caps? are you angry?

Comment: No @Ghost, just to get attention.

Answer (score 0):

Without a PHP code we cannot help.

MySQL works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e591f/1

EDITED:
Your framework most probably converts undefined datetime `NULL` to valid date time value `1970-01-01 00:00:00` which is the very beginning of PHP time - it equals to 0 (zero) second.

Some more info you can find on Codeigniter help: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Modify your table payment_date and set the column payment_date datatype to NULL DEFAULT NULL.

```
alter table payment_date modify column payment_date datetime null default null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
id, IF(payment_date='1970-01-01 00:00:00', null, payment_date) as payment_date 
FROM `student_detail`
```

[image]